# How can I authenticate a call to Dialogflow API v2 without installing gcloud?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to find instructions for authenticating to the Dialogflow API v2 without using gcloud. I'm using PHP, and all the examples I find say I need to install the Cloud SDK.

Are there instructions on how to do this without the Cloud SDK or can anyone please provide guidance?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Google supported client library](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/libraries/overview):

1. [Create a service account and download the private
   key](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/setup#sa-create).
2. [Set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var to your private key
   file](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/setup#auth-env).
3. The libray will now pickup the credentials from that file and handle
   auth for you.

If you are not using a Google supported client library, you need to
[implement the OAuth 2.0 protocol in your client](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2).